# Node app is not returning paths I want to see

Tags: node.js, api, routes, ejs

I have a node app using EJS for the templating engine.

I can see the documents fine when I look at the home page. I could add documents with a POST request as well. But when it came time to add an "edit document" page and button I started seeing 404 errors whenever I tried to add or edit my documents.

***My app.js:***

```
const app = express();   

app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.set('views', 'views');

const adminRoutes = require('./routes/admin');
const briefRoutes = require('./routes/brief');
const authRoutes = require('./routes/auth');


app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));    

app.use('/admin', adminRoutes);
app.use(briefRoutes);
app.use(authRoutes);

app.use(errorController.get404);
```

***My routes for add and edit pages:***

```
    router.get('/admin/add-brief', isAuth, briefsController.getAddBrief);

// /admin/add-brief => POST
router.post('/admin/add-brief', isAuth, briefsController.postAddBrief);

router.get('/admin/edit-brief/:briefId', briefsController.getEditBrief);

router.post('/admin/edit-brief', briefsController.postEditBrief);
```

***My controllers (note, GetBriefs is working. getAddBriefs and getEditBrief are not):***

//See everything

```
  exports.getBriefs = (req, res, next) => {
  Brief.find()
    .then(briefs => {
      res.render('brief', {
        Brief: briefs,
        pageTitle: 'All Briefs',
        path: '/',

      });
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.log(err);
    });
};
```

//Add a document

```
 exports.getAddBrief = (req, res, next) => {
        res.render('add-brief', {
          pageTitle: 'Add Brief',
          path: '/admin/add-brief',
          editing: false
        });
      };
```

//Edit a Document

```
 exports.getEditBrief = (req, res, next) => {
    const editMode = req.query.edit;
    if (!editMode) {
      return res.redirect('/');
    }
    const briefId = req.params.briefId;
      Brief.findById(briefId)
      .then(brief => {
        if (!brief) {
          return res.redirect('/');
        }
        res.render('edit-brief', {
          pageTitle: 'Edit Brief',
          path: '/admin/edit-brief',
          editing: editMode,
          brief: brief
        });
      })
      .catch(err => console.log(err));
  };
```

What am I missing? Or is there simply a typo that somehow has me stuck? The URLs are what I want to see "/admin/add-brief" and "edit-brief:Id" but I still get the 404 error.

Comment: Are you sure that the urls are correct? The routes for `add` and `edit` pages are inside briefRoutes?

Comment: They're inside adminRoutes. Which might explain why getting all routes works. It's something in my admin.js in my routes folder. 

But the URLs are: 

http://localhost:3002/admin/add-brief and http://localhost:3002/admin/edit-brief/5f2d8da2d0c490afc38af1d5?edit=true

Which is what I want to see. Except they aren't valid paths because I see the Page Not Found error.

Answer (score 1):

In your app.js file you have this line of code

```
app.use('/admin', adminRoutes);
```

That means that when url starts with `admin`, your code goes to `adminRoutes` file to find the proper route.

Now inside your adminRoutes file you have this route definition

```
router.get('/admin/add-brief', isAuth, briefsController.getAddBrief);
```

That means that in order to run `briefsController.getAddBrief` middleware the url has to be `localhost:3002/admin/admin/add-brief`.

See the difference? You have to delete the `admin` part of your route in adminRoutes.

```
router.get('/add-brief', isAuth, briefsController.getAddBrief);
```

Inside `adminRoutes` remove the `admin` part of url of all routes. You have declared it in app.js

Comment: Shouldn't I have been able to get to the page if I had typed "admin/admin/add-brief"?

Update: 

This was it with an additional wrinkle. I moved my add-brief.ejs and edit-brief.ejs pages out of an "admin" folder in my "views" directory and that solved the issue. Now the Post requests aren't quite working but at least I can see the forms. Thank you.